# how do I on OSX copy a folder from an external drive to my hard drive and only add the new files?

Tags: macos, filesystems, file-management, file-transfer

say I have on the external drive:

```
A/file1.txt
B/file2.txt
B/file3.txt
```

and on my hard drive I have:

```
A/file1.txt
B/file2.txt
```

I would like to drag and drop the whole folder over to the hard drive and have it ONLY copy B/file3.txt since that's the only new file and the other files did not change.

Answer (score 0):

ah ha, just type

```
rsync -rv test1/ test2/
```

Comment: Not a lot of drag&drop there though.

Comment: What are `test1` and `2`?